# A grunt task, script or application which removes unused assets?

Tags: javascript, performance, automation, gruntjs

Is anyone aware of a grunt task, script or application which removes unused assets?

I'm working on a project which has been through numerous rounds of amends, I'm looking to remove unused assets.

Anything will help!

Best wishes

Comment: That would be quite cool, I assume you also mean not adding them to a distribution folder rather than just deleting them completely.

Comment: To be honest, additional assets living in the source folder isn't the end of the world. It's primarily making sure they don't end up in the production build. I could probably write a script which does this, but it'd be good if there was something out there already with community support etc... why do something twice!

Comment: Well, it'd be a nice bit of automation. I could use it to decrease my app size. Always a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var _ = require('underscore'),
            assets = [],
            links = [],
            regex = new RegExp('(?:href|src|url)[\=\(][\'"](?!(?:http|#|\s|"))(.+?(?=jpg|png|mp4|pdf|js)?)[\'"]', 'ig');

    grunt.registerTask('cleanse', function () {
            getAssetsArray();
    });

    // get list of all assets
    function getAssetsArray () {
            grunt.file.expand({
                    filter: 'isFile',
                    cwd: 'app'
            }, ['assets/**/*']).forEach(function (file) {        
                    assets.push(file);
            });
            getLinkedAssets(assets);
    }

    // find links to assets in content
    function getLinkedAssets (assets) {
            grunt.file.expand({
                    filter: 'isFile',
                    cwd: 'app'
            }, ['**/*.html', '**/*.js', '**/*.css']).forEach(function (file) {        
                    var content = grunt.file.read('app/'+file);
                    while ((result = regex.exec(content)) !== null) {
                            links.push(result[1]);
                    }
            });
            removeAssets(assets, links);
    }

    // remove unused assets
    function removeAssets () {
            var remove = _.difference(assets, links);
            remove.forEach(function (el) {
                    console.log('Removed: '+el);
                    grunt.file.delete('app/'+el);
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good. You don't need the underscore dependency though, grunt provides this 'for free'. Change your code to `var _ = grunt.util._` :)

Answer (score 3):

Searching through npm and the official grunt website didn't turn anything up. I'm assuming by *unused assets* you mean files that aren't linked in any of your HTML files? For example if you have `image.jpg` and `image2.jpg` and only `image2.jpg` is referenced in your HTML then `image.jpg` is unused?

Write your own Chris; I can give you a starting point, but if you think it'd be a useful addition to a build chain you can always roll your own so that others benefit too. Here's a starting point that logs all the files relative to the Gruntfile in your project.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerMultiTask('unusedassets', function() {
        grunt.file.expand({
            filter: 'isFile'
        }, ['**/*']).forEach(function(file) {
            grunt.log.writeln(file);
        });
    }
};
```

From there, filter the filenames by the types you're interested in (images? css? js?), then check for the filename in the HTML source. Then, log the paths to the console of the unused assets (provide an option to automatically remove them, but I wouldn't enable this by default as it may throw up false positives).

Note; you may want to ignore `node_modules`.

You can [find all you need to get started on the wiki](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Creating-plugins).

Comment: Cheers Ben - I'm going to get on it. :)

Comment: Great stuff. Keep me posted.

Comment: In the end I went with the following solution: see below

Answer (score 0):

There is a grunt plugin that does exactly that. Get it at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-unused

Here's a little description of what it does:

> A Grunt task to check for unused files (jpg, png, css, js etc) in a
>   project files and output them to the console.

It can be configured to even delete the files. Just check out its config and you will know.